# Save form inputs to JS or PHP array OR to CSV file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, csv

I have a form with 2 input fields at the beginning and a button to add new field and I want to save everything user passed to an array or even better directly to CSV, because I'll be sending CSV file through and email at the end. I have tried a lot of methods but none worked for me.

Here's my code:
**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- STYLES -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="add_new_fields.js"></script>
    
    <title>Shopping form</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container1">
        <form id="form-info" method="POST">
            <input type="email" name='email' placeholder="Email" required>
            <input type="text" name="mytext[]" required id="text1">

    </div>
    <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp;
        <span>+</span>
    </button>
    <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Submit">
        </form>
    <p id="para"></p>

    
</body>

</html>
```

**add_new_fields.js**

```
console.log("add_new_field start");
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 14;
    var wrapper = $(".container1");
    var add_button = $(".add_form_field");
    var x = 0;


    $(add_button).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[] id="text1"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
        } else {
            alert('You Reached the limits. 15 fields are maximum.')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })

});
```

Comment: Fix your nesting of opening and closing tags, what you currently have there, makes little sense. And you’ll need to add your new fields to the form itself, not just to the container (then they would be _outside_ the form, and not get submitted with it in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

A way of getting in php
set the form action to the php file
Let I made a php file 'form.php'
So, in code First i set the form action

```
<form  action="form.php" id="form-info" method="POST">
            <input type="email" name='email' placeholder="Email" required>
            <input type="text" name="mytext[]" required id="text1">

    </div>
    <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp;
        <span>+</span>
    </button>
    <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

the to get the values in php file
The code of the form.php file shall be like this

```
<?php
 //save the email in a variable email
$email= $POST_["email"];   //here email inside [] is the name of input field
//then save text in variable text 
$text = POST_["mytext[]"];
//then save it in a array named input 
$input= array($email,$text);
 ?>
```